# Se puede pasar dos variables a envío de mail Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy mandando un mail con los datos del pedido, pero necesito pasar más de una variable, eso es posible??

**Controlador**

```
$pedido = Order::where('ticket', $id)->first();
$todosLosPedidos = Order::where('ticket', $id)->get();

Mail::to('info@email.es')->send(new Estado($pedido, $todosLospedidos));
```

**Mail Estado**

```
public $subject = 'High As - Cambio de estado de pedido';

    public $pedido, $todosLospedidos;

    public function __construct($pedido, $todosLospedidos)
    {
        $this->pedido = $pedido;
        $this->todosLospedidos = $todosLospedidos;
    }


    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.estado');
    }
```

Comment: ¿Probaste y no funciona?

Comment: No funciona, pero me acabo de dar cuenta que el "controlador" de mail, puedo hacer más querys con los valores que me vienen, así que seria una posible solución

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondo a mi propia pregunta por si a alguien le sirve. Lo que hecho es hacer las otras consultas dentro del controlador del Mail.

Aquí en el controlador general:

```
$pedido = Order::join('users', 'orders.id_cliente', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->select('orders.*', 'users.name AS elCliente', 'users.tipo_id AS elTipo', 'users.email AS elEmail')
                        ->where('orders.ticket', $id)->get();

        Mail::to('info@email.es')->send(new Estado($pedido)); 

        return redirect('mi-cuenta/pedidos-online')->with('info', 'Pedido editado correctamente!'

 );
```

Y en el controlador de `new Estado`

```
public $subject = 'High As - Cambio de estado de pedido';

    public $pedido;

    public function __construct($pedido)
    {
        $this->pedido = $pedido;

    }

    public function build()
    {
        $entrega = Direccion::where('id', $this->pedido[0]->entrega)->first();
        $facturacion = Direccion::where('id', $this->pedido[0]->facturacion)->first();
        $subtotal = DB::table('orders')
                        ->select('ticket', DB::raw('SUM(subtotal) as subtotal, SUM(iva) as iva, SUM(total) as total, SUM(envio) as envio'))
                        ->where('ticket', '=', $this->pedido[0]->ticket)
                        ->groupBy('ticket')
                        ->get();

        $transporte = User::join('paises', 'users.pais', '=', 'paises.codigo')
                         ->select('paises.importe', 'paises.pais')
                         ->where('users.id', $this->pedido[0]->id_cliente)->first();
        return $this->view('emails.estado')->with([ "entrega" => $entrega, "facturacion" => $facturacion, "subtotal" => $subtotal[0], "transporte" => $transporte]);
    }
```

No se si hay otra forma, pero así me a funcionado.